# How can a docker image be promoted to next environment by a Jenkins Job

Tags: docker, jenkins

We are using Jenkins for our CI/CD. We build and deploy docker images to a specific environment such as QA.

We would like to promote the same image to the next environment such as UAT once the image passes certain quality checks(in line with the build once principle)

How could we achieve this?

Comment: Are you using different registries for a different environment? How do you currently deliver an image to different environments? Do you use different tagging and use the same registry?

Comment: You need some system that allows to set and read some properties of some artifact depending on the build status. I think with the help of some software like [artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API) you could achieve this. Edit: Also, check out the Promote docker image section [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-PromoteDockerImage)